# Join between tables in Poco SQLite

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Altough SQLite supports relational databases, I am not sure this is implemented in Poco library. The unit tests from *poco-1.6.0-all/Data/SQLite/testsuite/src/SQLiteTest.cpp* don't seem to have an example and I couldn't find anywhere a clear confirmation that this is possible.

In their example from http://pocoproject.org/docs/00200-DataUserManual.html there is a simple select after a name:

```
std::string aName;
std::string match("Peter");
ses << "SELECT name FROM names WHERE name=?", into(aName), use(match), now;
```

Let's say I want to see the company Peter works for, from a different table containing the company descriptions, given the company ID:

```
// Untested
std::string aName;
std::string aCompany;
std::string match("Peter");
ses << "SELECT name, company_name FROM names, companies WHERE name=? AND company_id=2", 
    into(aName), into(aCompany), use(match), now;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an SQL question; here's how to do it with POCO:

```
Session tmp (Poco::Data::SQLite::Connector::KEY, "dummy.db");

tmp << "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Simpsons", now;
tmp << "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Companies", now;
tmp << "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Simpsons (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR)", now;
tmp << "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Companies (CompanyName VARCHAR, LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR)", now;

tmp << "INSERT INTO Simpsons VALUES(?, ?)", bind("Simpson"), bind("Bart"), now;
tmp << "INSERT INTO Simpsons VALUES(?, ?)", bind("Simpson"), bind("Homer"), now;

tmp << "INSERT INTO Companies VALUES(?, ?, ?)", bind("Microsoft"), bind("Simpson"), bind("Bart"), now;
tmp << "INSERT INTO Companies VALUES(?, ?, ?)", bind("Oracle"), bind("Simpson"), bind("Homer"), now;

std::string fname, lname, cname;
tmp << "SELECT P.FirstName, P.LastName, C.CompanyName "
        "FROM Simpsons P, Companies C "
        "WHERE P.FirstName = ? AND P.FirstName = C.FirstName", bind("Bart"), into(fname), into(lname), into(cname), now;

std::cout << lname << ',' << fname << " works for " << std::endl;
```

And the output:

> Simpson,Bart works for Microsoft

Comment: Indeed, this is an SQL question, however, I wanted to confirm that POCO SQLite implementation works as expected, as I didn't see any dependency to a well known external SQLite library (e.g.: SQLite C) when I compiled the POCO libraries, but instead, I think the logic is completely implemented in POCO.

Comment: SQLite is [embedded](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Data/SQLite/src/sqlite3.c) in POCO.